# finding a persian word in a string using php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string defined in PHP as follows:

```
$mystring="this is some text....
 این یک متن است. 

#محمد_حسن

........................";
```

How can I find the substring `#محمد_حسن` in the `mystring` variable and save it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
/([آ-ی]+)+/m
```

might be somewhat helpful.

#### Test

```
$re = '/([آ-ی]+)+/m';
$str = 'this is some text....
 این یک متن است.

#محمد_حسن

........................';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "محمد_حسن"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xhMofR/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/xhMofR/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---